# Unable to install mysql connector for Python 3.8.5

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I tried to install mysql connector using

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

It returned that

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/mysql-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/mysql-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/mysql-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/mysql-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/mysql-connector-python/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python
```

I also tried

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

and

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

All returned the same error. I even tried the MSI installation, which said

[image]

So, there is no MySQL connector for Python 3.8.5 now? What other packages should I use? Thanks!

Comment: *"ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.'…"* Fix your proxy!

Comment: @KlausD. thanks.... I turned off the proxy. It's fine now. Didn't realize that it is such a silly error.